# Android: CardView square reveal to new activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a RecyclerView with CardView items. I want to animate the CardView such that on click, the card enlarges, fills the screen and becomes a new activity with new elements. There is no shared element between the card and the activity. This is basically a square reveal. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved

Used CardView background and new Activity background as shared element.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22496423)

Comment: @Sree I am the author. I got my issue resolved. There was no need to downvote the post unnecessarily.